# Why does sudo su work, but su does not?

Tags: sudo, root, authentication, su

I have tried this on `Fedora` and on `Ubuntu`.

```
kshitiz@kshitiz:~$su
su: Authentication failure

kshitiz@kshitiz:~$sudo su

root@kshitiz:/home/kshitiz#
```

I am entering the same password in both the cases.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`su` requires the password of the account whose privileges you are trying to assume (apparently `root` in this case).

`sudo` requires the password of the current user - that is, the password for user `kshitiz`.

By running `sudo su`, you are effectively becoming `root`, then running `su` to get a root shell - that is, your privileges are already elevated to `root` before the call to `su` is executed, which is why you don't get prompted for the root password again.

Answer (score 1):

`su` uses the root password, while `sudo` uses the current user password. At least in Ubuntu the root password is scrambled during installation.

Comment: Isn't that a security loophole? Since any user in sudoers list can elevate to root what is the purpose of having a su account with scrambled password? Why doesn't setup just put the same password for su and kshitiz?

Comment: @KshitizSharma : The "su" password *in this case* is the *root* password. If you are asking, "what's the purpose of the root account?", methinks the caveat against using root has gone a bit far, lol -- but that would make a good separate question.  The reason you must be root to use `su` *with no arguments* is because it stands for "switch user" (not "super user") but, if you don't specify anything, the default is *root*.  You can, however, specify anyone, eg. "su kshitiz" -- in which case you would need kshitiz's password, not root's.  Make sense?

Comment: @KshitizSharma, yes, it is a hole. `sudo` is to give _selected_ users permissions to run _some_ programs as root (or other users). This way those users can run any program as root. It is a bit safer than letting Joe Random switch to root to do something (and stay there!), but not much better. As configuration for personal machines it is fine, elsewhere a much more careful configuration is required.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, you can specify in the `/etc/sudoers` file (use `visudo`) which password the user who issues `sudo` has to enter.  If these lines

```
# Defaults      targetpw
# ALL   ALL = (ALL) ALL
```

were uncommented, you would have to enter the root-password to run passwords with root-permissions via `sudo`.